# How to add a Gnome Panel

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors

I'm running gnome-session version 2.28.0.  I have three monitors.  The first two monitors combine to form X display :0.0 and everything is fine with that.  The third monitor is X display :0.1.

The third monitor (X Display :0.1) has no panels.  I would like to add Gnome panels to it.  How do I do this?  If I right-click, or ALT-right-click, or META-ALT-right-click, I don't see any option to add a panel.  I can start a terminal window on Display :0.1, but if I try to run gnome-panel, it complains that gnome-panel is already running.  What can I do?

Comment: From what I know, you can adjust gnome panels only in GNOME FlashBack session. Do you use it?